# Trying to forbid <p> tag only till text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a on click toggle function where I control my div. I have a FaQ section where user clicks on one topic and the bottom section appears but My `<p>` tag is coming across the whole line rather then just staying to the word..
Here is the image of what I am trying to say

[image]

I want that when user hovers general then only the mouse pointer should change where as now even if user takes the mouse to entire line the pointer changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
  $(".msg_body").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  $(".msg_head").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".msg_body").slideToggle(100);
  });
});
```

```css
.msg_head {
cursor: pointer;
cursor: hand;
font-size: 20px;
text-decoration: underline;
color: red;
float:left;
clear:both;
 }

  .msg_body {
  color: black;
   clear:both;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p class="msg_head"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" fa-2x></i>  <span>General:</span>
</p>
<div class="msg_body">
  <p class="msg_head" style="margin-left: 4em;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" fa-2x></i> sub question one of genral category</p>
  <div class="msg_body" style="margin-left: 4em;">
    answer to sub question one of genral category
  </div>
```

Comment: wrap the text 'general' in a `span`

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work

Comment: `<p>` is a block element by default. If you want inline display use inline elements or set display to inline

Comment: to add to @charlietfl 's reponse.. on your css `p{display:inline}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because for default `p` tags are block elements, taking all available space on `width`. Try adding this:

```
.msg_head {
  float:left;
  clear:both;
}
.msg_body {
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: @Raul glad to help U mate

Comment: need one more advice, when I click on General the bottom message appears but instead of -> arrow and I want to display a downwards arrow so that it feels like expanded any leads how to proceed? I think I need something like for every alternate click I need to change the arrow sign

Comment: @Raul are you using something like font-awesome ?

Comment: Yes I am using font awesome

Comment: @Raul one optin is rotate the actual arrow element like this http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1574/

Comment: tried this it doesnt work, I see it works in fiddle though see my updated question as my CSS has changed a bit
i.fa.open is not working it seems

Comment: Also when page loads for first time I see that everything(all my answers) displays for a sec and then hides so that user can click on General and see the questions am I loading it incorrectly?

Comment: @Raul try hidding items with CSS instead of JS

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a `<span>` clickable, instead of a `<p>`.
You can wrap it in `<p>` to keep it in block display.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //hide the all of the element with class msg_body
  $(".msg_body").hide();
  
  //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
  $(".msg_head").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().next(".msg_body").slideToggle(100);
  });
  
  console.log($('.msg_head'));
});
```

```css
.msg_head {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
.msg_body {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <span class="msg_head">
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" fa-2x></i> 
    General:
  </span>
</p>
<div class="msg_body">
  <p>
    <span class="msg_head" style="margin-left: 4em;">
      <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" fa-2x></i>
      sub question one of genral category
    </span>
  </p>
  <div class="msg_body" style="margin-left: 4em;">
    answer to  sub question one of genral category
  </div>
</div>
```